# send minus from jquery to php page

Tags: php, jquery

now i want send the - i mean Minus one to php
but when send it its not sending as a word
i cant tell you because i dont understand
see
in php when write `"$var"` its return `$var` value but when write '$var' its returm $var
how i can make this in jquery

```
var dataString = 'vote=-1';

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
     });
```

Comment: Uh? I don't exactly get your question but if you put a variable into double-quotes `"` then PHP substitutes the variable with its value. In single-quotes however it is treated like a normal string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272337/send-minus-from-jquery-to-php-page',
    type:'POST',
    data: 'vote="-1"'
});
```

Using `data: {vote:"-1"}` seems to convert `"-1"` to a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var vote_val = -1
$.ajax({
    url: "http://your-url.com/goes/here.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { vote: vote_val }
});
```